# What's my personality?

Tags: java, rags-to-riches

This is a [rags-to-riches](/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) take on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111623/using-contents-of-an-integer-array-to-print-a-string), specifically an improvement of [*my original answer*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112603/24141) there.

Copying my interpretation of the calculations involved from my answer:

Given a 70-character `String` for the [Keirsey Temperament Sorter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keirsey_Temperament_Sorter) test, e.g.

```
"ABABABaABABABaABABABaABABABaABABABaABABABaABABABaABABABaABABABaABABABa"
```

Responses are case-insensitive, and can even be 'unknown' (e.g. `-`). In other words, we only need to be concerned with the values `[AaBb]`.

1. Divide the 70 responses into 10 chunks of 7 responses each:

   ```
   ABABABaABABABaABABABa...ABABABa
   <- Q -><- R -><- S ->...<- Z ->

   ABABABa: chunk Q
   ABABABa: chunk R
   ABABABa: chunk S
   ...
   ABABABa: chunk Z
   ```
2. From each chunk, the 1st response goes into its own grouping, the 2nd *and* 3rd responses goes into the next, and finally the last two into the 4th grouping:

$$
A \rbrace 0 \\
\left.\begin{matrix}
B \\
A \\
\end{matrix}\right\rbrace 1 \\
\left.\begin{matrix}
B \\
A \\
\end{matrix}\right\rbrace 2 \\
\left.\begin{matrix}
B \\
a \\
\end{matrix}\right\rbrace 3
$$

3. Collate all the groupings across the 10 chunks, so that for the example, we have the following representations:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
Grouping & Count for A & Count for B\\
\hline
0 & 10 & 0 \\
\hline
1 & 10 & 10 \\
\hline
2 & 10 & 10 \\
\hline
3 & 10 & 10 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

4. Calculate the percentages of B responses per group, and the mapping the percentages to the trait is:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
Grouping & < 50\% & = 50\% & > 50\% \\
\hline
0 & E & X & I \\
\hline
1 & S & X & N \\
\hline
2 & T & X & F \\
\hline
3 & J & X & P \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

For the example, the derived personality is `EXXX` (group 0 has < 50% B responses, the rest are 50% exactly).

[My original answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112603/24141) chose a `Map<Choice, Map<Integer, Long>>` mapping of responses-to-grouping-to-count, which made the subsequent summation of responses per category slightly convoluted. For my revised implementation below, I used `Map<Integer, Map<Choice, Long>>`, i.e. grouping-to-responses-to-count, which makes the second-step summation easier.

```
public final class KeirseyTemperamentSorter {

    enum Choice {
        A, B, UNKNOWN;

        public static Choice of(char x) {
            try {
                return Choice.valueOf(String.valueOf(x).toUpperCase());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                return Choice.UNKNOWN;
            }
        }
    }

    private static final String[][] TRAITS = Stream.of("EXI", "SXN", "TXF", "JXP")
                                                    .map(v -> v.split(""))
                                                    .toArray(String[][]::new);
    private static final int CHUNK_LENGTH = 7;
    private static final int LENGTH = CHUNK_LENGTH * 10;
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 50;
    private static final Set<Choice> CHOICES = EnumSet.of(Choice.A, Choice.B);

    private KeirseyTemperamentSorter() {
        // empty
    }

    public static String getPersonality(String input) {
        return compute(validate(input)).entrySet().stream()
                .map(KeirseyTemperamentSorter::derive)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    private static String validate(String input) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(input).filter(v -> v.length() == LENGTH)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> {
                        return new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid responses"); });
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Map<Choice, Long>> compute(String input) {
        return IntStream.range(0, LENGTH).mapToObj(i -> map(input, i))
                    .map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Set::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, Collectors.counting())));
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Choice> map(String input, int i) {
        return Collections.singletonMap(((i % CHUNK_LENGTH) + 1) / 2,
                                            Choice.of(input.charAt(i)));
    }

    private static String derive(Entry<Integer, Map<Choice, Long>> x) {
        return TRAITS[x.getKey()][index(x.getValue().getOrDefault(Choice.B, 0L),
            CHOICES.stream().mapToLong(c -> x.getValue().getOrDefault(c, 0L)).sum())];
    }

    private static int index(long numerator, long denominator) {
        long value = Math.round(100.0 * numerator / denominator);
        return value < THRESHOLD ? 0 : value == THRESHOLD ? 1 : 2;
    }
}
```

For more information about the `map()` and `derive()` methods, please read my [original answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112603/24141).

My questions here:

- Is the `Map<Integer, Map<Choice, Long>>` type suitable for the problem at hand, as a starting point?

  - Should this be encapsulated into a wrapper class?
- Are there any alternative methods to performing the calculations?
- Any room for refactoring, code formatting, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a wrapper class, I can make the `compute()` step slightly easier:

```
private static final class Group {
    private final int group;
    private final Choice choice;

    private Group(int group, Choice choice) {
        this.group = group;
        this.choice = choice;
    }

    static Group of(String input, int i) {
        return new Group(((i % CHUNK_LENGTH) + 1) / 2, Choice.of(input.charAt(i)));
    }

    int getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    Choice getChoice() {
        return choice;
    }

    static final Collector<Group, ?, Map<Integer, Map<Choice, Long>>> COLLECTOR =
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Group::getGroup,
                            Collectors.groupingBy(Group::getChoice,
                                Collectors.counting()));
}

private static Map<Integer, Map<Choice, Long>> compute(String input) {
    return IntStream.range(0, LENGTH)
                    .mapToObj(i -> Group.of(input, i))
                    .collect(Group.COLLECTOR);
}
```

`Map.getOrDefault()` is used twice in the `derive()` method, so that can be extracted out if need be:

```
private static long get(Map<Choice, Long> map, Choice key) {
    return map.getOrDefault(key, 0L);
}

private static String derive(Entry<Integer, Map<Choice, Long>> x) {
    return TRAITS[x.getKey()][index(get(x.getValue(), Choice.B),
            CHOICES.stream().mapToLong(c -> get(x.getValue(), c)).sum())];
}
```